# Shapefile from selected features in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, vector-layer, writers

I am trying to develop a plugin to export selected features from a layer as shapefile.

I have a comboBox from which I can select features. After selecting features in comboBox, I tried following code but unable to get new shapefile of these particular features.

Initially I defined a location for exported shapefile by using push button.

```
    def select_output_file(self):
         filename, _filter = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
                   self.dlg, "Select   output file ","", '*.shp')
         self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

And then connect to this function:-

```
    def run(self):
           if self.first_start == True:
              self.first_start = False
              self.dlg = GetMapDialog()
              self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_output_file)
```

And after getting features in comboBox, I tried this:

```
# show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
      filename = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
      with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
          layer = selectedlayer ##U already add a main layer as selectedLayer
          selectedFeature = self.dlg.comboBox.currentText
          layer.select(selectedFeature)
          writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_file, 'utf-8', layer.crs(),'ESRI Shapefile', onlySelected=True)
          selected_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(output_file, '', 'ogr')
          del(writer)
```

After this, I got following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/DELL/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\get_map\get_map.py", line 226, in run
> writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_file, 'utf-8', layer.crs(),'ESRI Shapefile', onlySelected=True)
> TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
> overload 1: argument 2 has unexpected type '_io.TextIOWrapper'
> overload 2: argument 2 has unexpected type '_io.TextIOWrapper'
> overload 3: argument 2 has unexpected type '_io.TextIOWrapper'

How can I overcome this error by which I can export a shapefile of a particular feature?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [API Docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html?highlight=qgsvectorfilewriter) suggests that `writeAsVectorFormat` expects the 2nd argument to be a string containing the file name **not** a file object, which would match your error message.

> writeAsVectorFormat(layer: QgsVectorLayer, fileName: str, fileEncoding: str, destCRS: QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(), driverName: str = '', onlySelected: bool = False, datasourceOptions: Iterable[str] = [], layerOptions: Iterable[str] = [], skipAttributeCreation: bool = False, newFilename: str = '', symbologyExport: QgsVectorFileWriter.SymbologyExport = QgsVectorFileWriter.NoSymbology, symbologyScale: float = 1, filterExtent: QgsRectangle = None, overrideGeometryType: QgsWkbTypes.Type = QgsWkbTypes.Unknown, forceMulti: bool = False, includeZ: bool = False, attributes: Iterable[int] = [], fieldValueConverter: QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter = None) → Tuple[QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError, str]¶
>
> ```
> Write contents of vector layer to an (OGR supported) vector format
>
> Parameters
>
>         layer (QgsVectorLayer) – layer to write
>
>         fileName (str) – file name to write to
>
>         fileEncoding (str) – encoding to use
>
>         destCRS (QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()) – CRS to reproject exported geometries
>             to, or invalid CRS for no reprojection
>
>         driverName (str = '') – OGR driver to use
>
>         onlySelected (bool = False) – write only selected features of layer
>
>         errorMessage – will be set to the error message text, if an error occurs while writing the layer
>
>         datasourceOptions (Iterable[str] = []) – list of OGR data source creation options
>
>         layerOptions (Iterable[str] = []) – list of OGR layer creation options
>
>         skipAttributeCreation (bool = False) – only write geometries
>
>         newFilename (str = '') – QString pointer which will contain the new file name created (in case it is different to
>            fileName).
>
>         symbologyExport (QgsVectorFileWriter.SymbologyExport = QgsVectorFileWriter.NoSymbology) – symbology to export
>
>         symbologyScale (float = 1) – scale of symbology
>
>         filterExtent (QgsRectangle = None) – if not None, only features intersecting the extent will be saved (added in QGIS 2.4)
>
>         overrideGeometryType (QgsWkbTypes.Type = QgsWkbTypes.Unknown) – set to a valid geometry type to override the
>          default geometry type for the layer. This parameter allows for
>          conversion of geometryless tables to null geometries, etc (added in
>              QGIS 2.14)
>
>         forceMulti (bool = False) – set to True to force creation of multi* geometries (added in QGIS 2.14)
>
>         includeZ (bool = False) – set to True to include z dimension in output. This option is only valid if overrideGeometryType
>        is set. (added in QGIS 2.14)
>
>         attributes (Iterable[int] = []) – attributes to export (empty means all unless skipAttributeCreation is set)
>
>         fieldValueConverter (QgsVectorFileWriter.FieldValueConverter = None) – field value
>         converter (added in QGIS 2.16)
> ```